# Using dates from database column with calendar control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar

[image: task table]

I'm trying to work with the ASP calendar control and (for starters) highlight the specific days on the calendar that matches DueDate in the 'task' table. I know how to highlight a cell using the DayRender event, but how do I do this in accordance to the database table?

Would then also like to be able to click on the highlighted cell and see details of the task associated to that date in some sort of box next to the calendar.

Any pointers on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-code:

- Determine your desired date range (probably a certain month)
- Read all the tasks that have due dates within that date range (probably need `Name` and `DueDate` at least)
- In your `DayRender` handler you check if current day's date exists in the loaded tasks's due dates, if it does, highlight it with the color of your choice
- In you `SelectionChanged` handler you obtain the selected day's date, and look through the loaded list of tasks for any tasks that have that date as their due date, and populate whatever box with those tasks.

Comment: How do I obtain the selected day's date in the SelectionChanged event?

Comment: I think you'd need to set the `SelectionMode` to Day, and then you'd iterate through the selected days as shown in the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx